# Is there the right term for time points in hourly weather forecast?

Tags: terminology

Each hourly weather forecast has two columns with date and time. The first column: forecast creation date and time (the column (1) in a table below). The second column: forecast hour (the column (2) in the table below).

Is there an established term for the second column? Points? Slices?

- [The Weather Company](https://weather.com/weather/hourbyhour/l/USNY0996:1:US) uses 'Time' name for this column.
- [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs) uses 'Output Timestep' name for this column in the GFS forecast model.

And also, is there the right term for the first column?

```
Table with example of hourly weather forecast
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Forecast Creation  | Forecast Hour | Temperature, K |
| Date and Time (1)  |       (2)     |      (3)       |
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 2019-03-28, 00-00  | +0            | 303            |
| 2019-03-28, 00-00  | +3            | 305            |
| 2019-03-28, 00-00  | +6            | 307            |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 2019-03-28, 06-00  | +0            | 307            |
| 2019-03-28, 06-00  | +3            | 308            |
| 2019-03-28, 06-00  | +6            | 309            |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

I spotted that a scientific paper [1] uses the "lead time" term, and then its definition [2] was found from the Glossary of Meteorology by the American Meteorological Society.

> **forecast lead time**
>
> The length of time between the issuance of a forecast and the
> occurrence of the phenomena that were predicted.

[1] https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103/S106837391405001X

[2] http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Forecast_lead_time